# Maximum number "C"

Tags: c, file-io

i'm a begginer in programming and i have a task. I need to find the maximum number from file `in.txt` with content: 2,5,4,6,7,10 and then write it to file `out.txt`. `Language C`. The problems are:

1. I'm not very good in programing and in english(so if u will try to explane me something in english i don't think that i'll understand every word)
2. In the end there should be the max number on da screen, but it shows me the very first number
3. It's not my first theme here and every time the moderator give a link were i can read some text and find the answer, but look at priblem(1) there are too much text and i cannot tranlate everything in those answers(themes)
   So help me please i'm a noob/ I have some code:

   ```
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   main()
   {
       int N, max;
       FILE *F;

       F = fopen("in.txt", "r");   // open file
       FILE *G;

       G = fopen("out.txt", "w");  // open file
       fscanf(F, "%d", &max);
       while (feof(F))
       {
           fscanf(F, "%d", &N);
           if (max < N)
               max = N;
       }
       printf("max=%d", max);      // show the result on the screen
       fprintf(G, "%d", max);      // put result into out.txt
       fclose(F);
       fclose(G);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if fopens succeed. Check if scanf succeed.
scanf will fail at EOF and drop out of loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int N,max;
    FILE*F;
    F=fopen("in.txt","r"); //open file
    if ( F == NULL) { // check if fopen failed
        printf ( "could not open in.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE*G;
    G=fopen("out.txt","w"); //open file
    if ( G == NULL) {
        fclose ( F);
        printf ( "could not open out.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ( ( fscanf(F,"%d",&max)) == 1) // read an int into max. if success return is 1
    {
        while( ( fscanf(F,"%d",&N)) == 1) // read an int into N. if success return is 1
        {
            if(max<N)
            {
                max=N;
            }
        }
        printf("max=%d",max);//show the result on the screen
        fprintf(G,"%d",max); //put result into out.txt
    }
    fclose(F);
    fclose(G);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank u for helping, but there is something wrong. In result it shows me the very first number 2

Comment: Oh, thank u very much it is working. U totaly solve the problem

Comment: Note: if `fscanf(F,"%d",&max)` does not return 1, `printf("max=%d",max)` is UB.  The printing of `max` should be within `if ( ( fscanf(F,"%d",&max)) == 1) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Typo:

```
while(!feof(F))
      ^--- missing
```

`feof` returns `TRUE` if you're at the end of the specified file handle. Since you just started reading that file, you're **NOT** at the end, so `feof()` will return `FALSE`, and terminate your loop. You never actually read any further numbers.

Adding the `!` makes it into "while NOT at the end of the file, read numbers".

Comment: Actually, `feof` is meaningful only when some read has failed. So you should `do{`...`}while(!feof(f))`; also `fscanf` gives some result. Read more about [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) & [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html)

Comment: @Basile: Considering there was an `fscanf` call before the loop, it needs to be a `while` loop, not a `do...while` loop here.

Comment: Using `feof` to decide when to terminate an input loop is a bad idea. Instead, check the result returned by the input function (read its documentation to see what it returns to indicate failure). If there's an *error* rather than a normal end-of-file condition, `feof()` will never return true (`ferror()` will return true), and you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: Adding `!` in `int N, max; ... while (!feof(F)) { fscanf(F, "%d", &N); if (max < N) max = N; }` is still a problem.  Consider only 1 `int` is in the file.  It is read as `max`.  Then the first call to `fscanf(F, "%d", &N)` returns `EOF` and `N` is never set.  The following `if (max < N)` results in UB.